VB6 library causes System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException in visual studio 2022 (works in visual studio 2019)
I've an old .net framework 4.8 project that imports a very old vb6 library.
To make work project I need to register in SYSWOW64 that dll using regsvr32.
I've no problem until visual studio 2019.
But in visual studio 2022 I get this error:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {9558A4C8-5107-47A2-96A0-532DE1E12940} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

How can I solve?
Thanks
Edit:
if you try import dll as com reference from visual studio 2022 I get

No problem with visual studio 2019

I Have solved enabling 32 bit execution Tools
-> Options
-> Projects and Solutions
-> Web Projects
-> Uncheck "Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects"`

You should post that as a full answer :)
